# In Railo Express 4.2, DateTimeFormat method on database variable fails

Tags: datetime, railo

We have a ColdFusion web application (created by a different organization) that we are trying to move to Railo Express v4.2 http://www.getrailo.org/ (on a different Windows server).

So far, everything seems to work except for the DateTimeFormat or DateFormat methods when attempting to format a date/time value retrieved from the database (SQL Server).

DateFormat(Now(),'dddd, m/d/yyyy') works correctly in Railo, but a similar DateFormat call on a variable retrieved from a datetime column in the database fails with an error message like:

"can't convert value {ts '2014-12-11 14:08:21'} to a datetime value"

It's possible that I don't have something configured correctly in the datasource in Railo, or in the system configuration for Railo.

In the ColdFusion server, the method "getMetadata" on the variable containing a database datetime value returns "java.sql.Timestamp". In Railo, the method "getMetadata" on the same variable returns "java.lang.String". In Railo, getMetadata for "Now()" returns "railo.runtime.type.dt.DateTimeImpl".

When searching for this issue, the only entry I could find was a bug in an older version of Railo which has since been fixed.

Can anyone suggest any configuration settings that I may need to adjust in Railo, or any troubleshooting steps that I can take to investigate potential causes of this issue?

===========================================

In Railo:

<cfoutput>#session.LastLoginDate#</cfoutput> returns {ts '2014-12-12 11:11:10'}

<cfoutput>#dateFormat("{ts '2014-12-12 11:11:10'}",'dddd, m/d/yyyy')#</cfoutput> returns Friday, 12/12/2014

But (combining the two), <cfoutput>#dateFormat(session.LastLoginDate,'dddd, m/d/yyyy')#</cfoutput> **fails** with: Can't cast String [{ts '2014-12-12 11:11:10'}] to a value of type [datetime]

Comment: What does this code give you on Railo: `<cfoutput>#dateFormat("{ts '2014-12-11 14:08:21'}",'dddd, m/d/yyyy')#</cfoutput>`. It's not exactly the same as your situation, but that works fine for me.

Comment: That returns: Thursday, 12/11/2014

Comment: If this data is coming from a database, how is it ending up in a session variable?  I'm wondering if there is a line of code something like <cfset session.LastLoginDate = "#qryFoo.LastLoginDate#">.  This wouldn't explain the whole thing, but if there is something like this, changing it to <cfset session.LastLoginDate = qryFoo.LastLoginDate> would likely prevent the value from being coerced to a string type.